# How can I group files and create archives accordingly?

Tags: linux, unix, shell

How can I group files and create archives accordingly?

I have 10,000 files in a folder (no sub-folders) and I want to create 10 zip or tar.gz archives. This means every archive has 1,000 files.

How can I do this in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` to get all the filenames, and redirect the output to a file outside of the directory. Use `split` to split that file into 10 pieces. At that point, check to see what option the archiving tool has to read a list of files either from a file or from standard input, and use it accordingly.